# Make JSTree Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, jstree, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm working in a treeview with JSTree plugin and Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2
So, I'm trying to make it responsive, without success. once the display width is smaller than the jsTree Element, the text inside doesn't break and my layout goes to space.

I also would like to change the size of the arrows (highlighted below):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't test ist, but on the jsTree site it is said, that it has a built-in responsive theme: http://www.jstree.com/docs/config/

I guess you enable it by using the responsive option: http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.defaults.core.themes.responsive